# Copying Devanagari on OS X

Tags: macos, copy-paste, unicode

I am working with several files in various formats (PDF, HTML, DOCX) that contain Devanagari (Indian) script.

When I try to copy text using either CMD+C or the right-click menu, it is transformed into latin letters immediately:
[image]

Both the copy source (Safari in this case) and target (TextEdit) support Devanagari script.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks as if the pdf file did not use unicode but embedded a special font with ASCII bindings for Devanagari characters.
There probably won’t be an automatic way to transform this into unicode characters.

As an alternative, you could try to find the original font and use that. (Maybe start with [this font](http://www.kiranfont.com/kf/layout.asp).) Of course this will not solve the problem for any other users of the document.